# Finding nil has_one associations in where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This may be a simple question, but I seem to be pulling my hair out to find an elegant solution here. I have two ActiveRecord model classes, with a has_one and belongs_to association between them:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :purchase
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to find all Item objects, that have no purchase object associated with them, ideally without resorting to having a boolean `is_purchased` or similar attribute on the Item.

Right now I have:

```
purchases = Purchase.all
Item.where('id not in (?)', purchases.map(&:item_id))
```

Which works, but seems inefficient to me, as it's performing two queries (and purchases could be a massive record set).

Running Rails 3.1.0

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's quite common task, SQL OUTER JOIN usually works fine for it. Take a look [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), for example.

In you case try to use something like

```
not_purchased_items = Item.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases ON purchases.item_id = items.id").where("purchases.id IS null")
```

Comment: That link is perfect! The join is pretty much exactly what I needed, I just had to substitute the where above with `where("purchases.item_id IS null")` and it's good to go. Thanks!

Comment: If using `has_many` or `has_one` you can achieve the join without having to write the actual query using `Item.join(:purchases)`

Answer (score 34):

Found two other railsey ways of doing this:

```
Item.includes(:purchase).references(:purchase).where("purchases.id IS NULL")

Item.includes(:purchase).where(purchases: { id: nil })
```

Technically the first example works without the 'references' clause but Rails 4 spits deprecation warnings without it.

Comment: While this is more succinct than the accepted answer, it will load all of the data from the associated table. If you want to keep your SQL query nice and tidy, use the custom join that @dimuch suggested instead.

Comment: @deadwards I don't think that's true.  `Asset.includes(:attachments).where(attachments: { id: nil})` produces: `SELECT "assets"."property_id" AS t0_r0, ... "attachments"."updated_at" AS t1_r7 FROM "assets" LEFT OUTER JOIN "attachments" ON "attachments"."property_id" = "assets"."property_id" WHERE "attachments"."id" IS NULL`, same as @dimuch's example.

Comment: Rails 4 way: `Item.includes(:purchases).references(:purchases).where(purchases: { id: nil })`.  If you call to_sql on it, you'll see it definitely doesn't load all data.  It does exactly the same thing as the accepted answer.

Comment: @bronson - Should be: `Item.includes(:purchase).references(:purchases).where(purchases: { id: nil })`; No "s" on `includes(:purchase)`

Answer (score 16):

A more concise version of @dimuch solution is to use the [`left_outer_joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins) method introduced in Rails 5:

```
Item.left_outer_joins(:purchase).where(purchases: {id: nil})
```

Note that in the `left_outer_joins` call `:purchase` is singular (it is the name of the method created by the `has_one` declaration), and in the `where` clause `:purchases` is plural (here it is the name of the table that the `id` field belongs to.)

Comment: Can you specify Rails version? I believe this is > 5.

Answer (score 8):

Rails 6.1 has added a query method called `missing` in the `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain` class.

It returns a new relation with a left outer join and where clause between the parent and child models to identify missing relations.

Example:

```
Item.where.missing(:purchase)
```