# Rails: Query nil has_one association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.3

I have two models: `Patient` and `CodeStatus`.

CodeStatus `belongs_to` Patient, and Patient `has_one` CodeStatus

I am trying to query all patients where `patient.code_status` is nil. I was surprised to find that `Patient.where(code_status: nil)` does not work throwing: `column patients.patient_id does not exist`

I have already found [this (fairly old) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515268/finding-nil-has-one-associations-in-where-query), but I find it difficult to believe that the best way to query this is via a long string of raw SQL. I would think that rails would include this helper like they do for many other associations. Does anyone know of a less verbose solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couple questions: 1) What's the output of `Patient.primary_key` and `CodeStatus.primary_key`? 2) Why is the query looking for a patients.patient_id column to begin with? By default it should be expecting the primary key to be `patients.id`... 3) Can you add the entire has_one/belongs_to lines to your question? Are you passing any options to those methods? 4) Can you add the db/schema for those two tables?

Comment: `where(column: nil)` is supported and generates `WHERE "table"."column_name" IS NULL` with postgres. You probably messed up with the association definition. If `CodeStatus` belongs to `Patient`, `CodeStatus` must have a `patient_id` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that

```
patient.code_status
```

is not a column, but a method, added by Rails when you say

```
class Patient
  has_one :code_status
end
```

Here is how you'd get all patients not associated with any code status:

```
Patient.includes(:code_status).where(code_statuses: { id: nil })
```