# In 1-to-many Rails ActiveRecord relation, what is the best practice to get parent records that they only have children records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Post` model that has many `comments`

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

How do I get distinct posts that have comments excluding the posts that do not have comments?

I believe that `Post.joins(:comments).distinct("posts.*")` does the job.

Is there any better alternative?

I emphasize that the result should not have duplicate entries of posts, which is what happens when we join with comments (one-to-many relationship).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this again, and considering Mark's comment to my original solution, the simplest solution may just be to drop the `"posts.*"` from your original.

```
Post.joins(:comments).distinct
```

Comment: This is better to my suggestion, only because one has to type less. The SQL generated is exactly the same even if you exclude the `"posts.*"`. So, I will accept it. Just want to wait if anyone else comes up with a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

This works, though obviously a matter of taste as to whether it is better:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:comments).where.not(comments: {id: nil})
```

And `left_outer_joins` came in with Rails 5, so with earlier versions a more verbose solution is needed. See [Finding nil has_one associations in where query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515268/finding-nil-has-one-associations-in-where-query)

The nicest thing about it, is it pairs nicely with the opposite query:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:comments).where(comments: {id: nil})
```

Which is all the posts without comments

Comment: I believe that your solution is not exactly what I am looking for, since it returns each Post multiple times, equal to the number of its corresponding Comments. I would like to get a relation that would return the Posts only once for each one of them.

Comment: If you want only unique records, just add `.uniq` to the end of the query, but either way I think I prefer your version to be honest

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to really use `distinct` at the end, it's not at all effective as you are selecting everything by default (`posts.*`) which has a unique primary key (`id`) for each record.

```
Post.joins(:comments)
# SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
```

*Note:*

To see the difference yourself please try to run below queries.

```
Post.joins(:comments).count
Post.joins(:comments).distinct.count

# Both should be giving you the same numbers.
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer to my question. See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734392/in-1-to-many-rails-activerecord-relation-what-is-the-best-practice-to-get-paren/59734844#comment105619057_59734844

Comment: I did not see your comment. I believe many won't, because it takes an extra effort to read all comments in all the answers ;) 

Can you please update your question?

Also with the expectation in your comment, the best way is to go with @ReggieB's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using subquery:

```
Post.where(id: Comment.select(:post_id).distinct)
```

Load time depends on the number of comments in the database.